# Ubuntu 19.10 Bluetooth Not showing Devices

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 on Dell Inspiron 7347. I am trying to connect my Bluetooth speaker with the laptop but the laptop can't detect my Bluetooth speaker. Then I scanned for other devices but it can't detect any of them.
My laptop is also not visible on my Samsung phone despite the visibility of the laptop is turned on. I have also installed Blueman.

I used these commands :

```
shubh@Cosmos:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# Pairable on
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Changing pairable on succeeded
```

Please tell me what must I do to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

worked well for me.